# Setting a default value in a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list. MY objective is to set the dropdown list to "default" on load

```
<b>Filter Within Months:</b>
<select  class="btn green" ng-model="myOptions" ng-options="i.label for i in items track by i.id" ng-change="selectedItemChanged()">
</select>
```

controller.js
setting the model to "Default" on load.

```
$scope.myOptions.id = 0;
$scope.items = [{
  id: 0,
  label: 'Default'
}, {
  id: 1,
  label: 'All'
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: '3 month'
}, {
  id: 3,
  label: '6 month'
}, {
  id: 4,
  label: 'Previous Month'
}];

$scope.selectedItemChanged = function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var endDate = Date.now();
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
  var firstDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() - 1, 1)
  var lastDayOfPreviousMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0)

  if ($scope.myOptions.id === 1) { //show All
    startDate = null;
  } else if ($scope.myOptions.id === 2) { //show 3 month
    startDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 90);
  } else if ($scope.myOptions.id === 3) { //show 6 month
    startDate = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 180);
  } else if ($scope.myOptions.id === 4) { //show Previous Month
    startDate = Date.parse(firstDayOfPreviousMonth);
    endDate = Date.parse(lastDayOfPreviousMonth);
  } else { //Default
    startDate = Date.parse(firstDay)
  }
  $scope.selectedDateFilterRange();
}

$scope.selectedDateFilterRange = function() {
  //filter the data
}
```

but whenever im running the code an error appears

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined at
>   $scope.myOptions.id = 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a property of an **undefined object**: `myOptions` does not exist.

Change `$scope.myOptions.id = 0;`

To:

```
$scope.myOptions = { "id": 0 };
// Or $scope.myOptions = {};
//    $scope.myOptions.id = 0;
```

### [Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q2tnm4xx/1)

Comment: i do have one doubt . If we are changing to other option such as "All" will
the initialized value $scope.myOptions = { "id": 0 }; affect it and change it back to "Default"?

Comment: @NithinP.H It will work as expected. Try it on [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/q2tnm4xx/1).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var index = _.findIndex($scope.items,{id:0});
$scope.myOptions = $scope.items[index];
```

Note: The first line requires underscore.js but you can replace it with pure javascript to get the **index** of the item with id = 0 from **$scope.items**

Comment: This is not how you should proceed *when using AngularJS*.

Answer (score -2):

1. $("#dropdownId").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
2. document.getElementById("#dropdownId").selectedIndex = 0

Comment: the above issue was related to an object "myOptions " being undefined and trying to set a property "id" for and undefined object. Therefore declaring 
myOptions = { "id": 0 }; will suffice